# Is the parseInt() method in Javascript part of what Object? Math object? String Object?

Tags: javascript, oop

I understand that everything in Javascript are objects, e.g. all the mathematical *methods/functions* such as `Math.sin()`, `Math.round()` etc belong to the Math Object. I have however not found out what is the object of the `parseInt()` method, I have searched the MDN but I am not satisfied with the answers there?

Comment: which object? thats only a public function

Comment: "Everything is an object" – yes, `parseInt` is an object. That doesn't mean everything has to be a *method on an object*.

Comment: In my understanding, its a part of `window`. Since these are public properties, the have to be at highest scope for everyone to have access to